# Adodb in php don't connect

Tags: php, adodb, adoconnection

I have a config file on my page and inside of it i have something like this:

```
<?php
    include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
    session_start();
    $db_user = 'dbuser';
    $db_pass = 'dbpass';
    $db_name = 'dbname';
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    echo "OK";
    $db = NewADOConnection('mysql');
    echo "OK";
    $db -> Connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("Błąd połączenia z bazą danych!");
    echo "OK!";
?>
```

And when I execute this scirpt on my screen I see only one OK, so the problem must be in the fucton NewADOConnection, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Why don't you look in `NewADOConnection()`?

Comment: remove the `&` from `$db = &NewADOConnection('mysql');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
    session_start();
    $db_user = 'dbuser';
    $db_pass = 'dbpass';
    $db_name = 'dbname';
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    echo "OK";
    $db = NewADOConnection('mysql');
    echo "OK";
    $db -> Connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("Błąd połączenia z bazą danych!");
    echo "OK!";
?>
```

Simply remove the & before NewADOConnection. A & is a pointer in PHP. You dont want pointers here

Read about pointers here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Read about ADOdb here:
http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried without &, and still I have the same effect.